# Trying to get the value when Radio Button is clicked

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String value = ((radio1) findViewById).getText().toString();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzatype);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Pizzatype.this, Overview.class);
    intent.putextra("Bbread","Brown Bread");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: findViewById requires the id you mentioned in your layout file, can you post the contents of your activity_pizzatype.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't say what is the ID of radiobutton

Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzatype);
        RadioButton rButton = (RadioButton) findViewbyId(R.id.radiobutton)
        String rText = rButton.getText().toString()
        Intent intent = new Intent(Pizzatype.this, Overview.class);
        intent.putextra("Bbread","Brown Bread ");
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

and define RadioButton as follow:

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton"
        android:text="option1"/>
```